# State of the art values for Shor algorithm depth and number of qubits on Clifford+T basis with arbitrary connectivity

Tags: quantum-algorithms, shors-algorithm

I am trying to find the **state of the art** results in term of number of logical qubits and depth for the Shor factoring algorithm **on the Clifford+T basis**.

I don't want to assume anything about the error correcting code used, let's say I have my "own way" of doing the gates (so I don't want to assume restricted connectivity). I also want **concrete numbers and not asymptotic behaviors**.

There are many papers discussing it but what is frequent is that they either provide asymptotic behaviors instead of concrete number, either they provide the number of logical qubits and $T$ gates but not the algorithm depth, either they assume a nearest neighbor connectivity for the logical qubits.

For instance, I found out a [recent paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.09749.pdf) on the topic, but it assumes nearest neighbor connectivity and doesn't provide the algorithm depth.

Would it be a fair assumption to consider that the number of Toffoli+T/2 gates provided in this paper (i) is a fair estimation of the total number of logical gates $N_{\text{gates}}$, (ii) can be highly parallelized such that the number of logical qubits $N_{\text{qubits}}$ verifies:

$$N_{\text{qubits}} \times Depth \approx N_{\text{gates}}$$

Because if so I could easily estimate the depth knowing $ N_{\text{gates}}$ and $N_{\text{qubits}}$ from this paper.